# Retry downstream jenkins job if tag doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have Jenkins job (let's call it DeployJob) which triggers another Jenkins job (let's call it BuildJob) both using declarative pipelines.

```
  build job: "BuildJob/${buildConfig.deployConfig.tag}", parameters: [
    [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'DEPLOY',             value: true]
  ]
```

In DeployJob, `buildConfig.deployConfig.tag` contains a tag in the repository of *BuildJob* which may not have been discovered yet, either because the hook has not been processed yet, or because the **Scan Multibranch Pipeline** service has not yet run.

Is there a mechanic that allows me to either trigger the *Scan Multibranch Pipeline* of the Repository behind BuildJob? or to wait for (or retry later) if the tag (hence the job) is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, you should be able to use the [retry](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) directive here. Here is a Pipeline with some retry logic.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
    stage("A"){
        steps{
            script {
                retry(count: 3) {
                     sleep 60
                     build job: "BuildJob/${buildConfig.deployConfig.tag}", wait: false, parameters: [
    [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'DEPLOY', value: true]
  ]                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you put it inside a `script{}` block? seems to work without it...

Comment: @JoSSte nope you don't need the `Script {}`. unless you want to use some Groovy code to conditionally retry etc.